# React-router-dom Router not working. Jumps to 404 page only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working with react router on a small project. I initially had my `AppRouter` working with `BrowserRouter` and everything works fine. But I had to switch to `Router` so I could add my own history object. With `Router` my page navigations do not work, instead it jumps straight to my 404 page. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong will be appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import AddExpensePage from "../components/AddExpensePage";
import EditExpensePage from "../components/EditExpensePage";
import ExpenseDashboardPage from "../components/ExpenseDashboard";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import HelpPage from "../components/HelpPage";
import NotFoundPage from "../components/NotFoundPage";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import LoginPage from "../components/LoginPage";

import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Try and put the switch inside the  BrowserRouter.

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine what do you mean ? I have a Switch in there

Comment: Keep using `BrowserRouter` and use `useHistory` hook to get access to `history` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you keep using `BrowserRouter`. React Hooks now make using history possible despite the type of Router you're using.

From [ReactRouter documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks), `useHistory` is there to your rescue:

> The `useHistory` hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.

To access the `history` object anywhere in your app inside the Routed Components, you can do the following inside of that component:

`let history = useHistory();`

Then you have access to `history.push()` and other methods you wish to call to fiddle with `history`.

---

Conclusion:

Don't switch to `<Router>`, keep using `<BrowserRouter>` and use hooks to access `history` using `useHistory`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrapp your routes with `BrowserRouter` component, for example:

```js
const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: No problem! Glad It helped you!